# adding buttons in fragments android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

I'm trying to create an App with fragments and in fragments I want to add buttons.
Here is the code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

import com.example.lightcontrolsystem.R;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTabContent();

    }

    private void setTabContent() {
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);



        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("Pattern list").setIndicator("Pattern List",
                        getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                PatternListFragment.class, null);

               }
}
```

Here is the fragment I want to add buutons:

```
public class PatternListFragment extends Fragment {

Button Theme1, Theme2, Theme3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.patterns_list, container,false);
    //Theme1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.theme1);


//  Theme1.setOnClickListener(buttonTheme1tOnClickListener);

    return view;
}
}
```

I tried to add a buuton, But I can see some errors in findViewById(R.id.theme1)

`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/theme1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="theme1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`

```
`<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost >
`
```

How Can I add button handlers in Fragment ? is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see some errors in findViewById(R.id.theme1)

Use

```
 Theme1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.theme1);
 // use the view object to find views
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29)

or in `onActivityCreated`

```
 Theme1 = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.theme1);
```

Also follow java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

In fragment you are inflating a view,so you have to get all the id with the refernce of that view.below is the code sample.

```
public class PatternListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Button Theme1, Theme2, Theme3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.patterns_list, container,false);
Theme1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.theme1);
Theme1.SetOnClickListener(this);

return view;
 }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Theme1:

        break;
// same way for other buttons
    default:
        break;
   }
   }

}
```

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks, above solution worked. Now I have a different problem My Tab/Fragment and Button are overlapping. How can I fix this in my .xml file ?

Comment: my main.xml file added above

Comment: @ashok449 post a different question for a new problem